# Ruby PageObject, visiting webpages outside of step defintions

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I am trying to call page object methods outside of my step definitions for visiting pages so I can avoid duplication within my steps. I believe the issue now is with how I am creating my browser session, and the object I created in my hooks is not accessible by anything outside of other hooks / steps definitions.

Directory structure:
              
`├── features/
│   ├── Gemfile
│   ├── feature_files
│   │   ├── example1.feature
│   │   ├── example2.feature
│   ├── hooks
│   │   ├── web_hooks.rb
│   ├── step_definitions
│   │   ├── web_steps.rb
│   ├── Support
│   │   ├── example1.feature
|   |   |   |──pages
|   |   |   |   |──test.rb
|   |   |   |──controller
|   |   |   |   |──controller.rb`

My Web hooks are nothing more than the basic new watir session + logging:

`@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)`

So when I am visiting my pages within my step definitions that all works as expected, but when I change my step to call a method outside of the step definitions I get back.

```
Unable to pick a platform for the provided browser or element: nil.
      nil was passed to the PageObject constructor instead of a valid browser or element object.
```

My controller class looks like this:

```
class TestController

  class << self
    include PageObject
    include PageObject::PageFactory

    def test_visit(url)
      visit TestPage, :using_params => {:id => url} do |page|
        page.populate
        embed(@browser.screenshot.base64, 'image/png', "STUB Setup for #{code}")
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I have several variations of the above controller including turning it into a module and extending pageobject functionality, trying to pass @browser into the method from the step definition etc but they all result in the following. I have also tried requiring everything under my support structure prior to running my cucumber tests.

Answer (score 1):

The `visit` method assumes that `@browser` is defined and available. You will need to define it within the `test_visit` method.

**Passing browser instance**

The most straightforward solution may be to pass in the `Watir::Browser` object:

```
def test_visit(url, browser)
  @browser = browser
  visit TestPage, :using_params => {:id => url} do |page|
    page.populate
    embed(@browser.screenshot.base64, 'image/png', "STUB Setup for #{code}")
  end
end
```

With the step definitions presumably looking like:

```
TestController.test_visit('some_url', @browser)
```

If you are making a lot of calls to the `TestController` and always using the same browser instance, you could setup a `@browser` in the class. This would save you from having to always pass in the browser instance.

```
class TestController
  class << self
    include PageObject
    include PageObject::PageFactory

    def browser=(browser)
      @browser = browser
    end

    def test_visit(url)
      visit TestPage, :using_params => {:id => url} do |page|
        page.populate
        embed(@browser.screenshot.base64, 'image/png', "STUB Setup for #{code}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In your web hooks, where you start the browser, you could configure the `TestController` to have the browser instance:

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
TestController.browser = @browser
```

Then your step definitions do not need to pass in the `@browser`:

```
TestController.test_visit('some_url')
```

**Make methods available to step definitions**

Another option is to make the shared methods directly available to step definitions. As the methods will be in the scope of the step, `@browser` and `embed` will be available.

First, define your methods in a module:

```
module TestController
  def test_visit(url)
    visit TestPage, :using_params => {:id => url} do |page|
      page.populate
      embed(@browser.screenshot.base64, 'image/png', "STUB Setup for #{code}")
    end
  end
end
```

In your `env.rb` (or similar), make the module methods available to the step definitions by using `World`:

```
World(TestController)
```

Your step definitions can then simply call the methods directly:

```
test_visit('some_url')
```

Comment: Creating this `TestController` seems a bit cumbersome. Depending on what the shared methods are, it might make more sense to make the methods directly available to the step definitions via Cucumber's `World`.

Comment: Hi Justin, could you expand on that World point? I incorperated the change you mentoned above but it doesn't recognise the browser methods like .embed etc, although it will elsewhere within the steps?

Comment: @Curious_Bop, I added an example of using `World`. Taking this approach should allow `embed` to also be available.